# Bootstrap Tour Attaching to elements that move

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap tour and I am attaching each step to an object, but these objects could be moved around using jquery drag and drop to different divs.

Could someone please provide me with an example of how I should do such an implementation.

Thanks

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
this.tour.addSteps([
                {element: $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first(),
                 title: "1",
                 content: "Access scheduling tools by clicking on the card to flip it over.",
                 placement: "bottom",
                 onNext: function () {
                     $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first().click();
                 }
                },
                {element: $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first().find(".pause"),
                 title: "2",
                 content: "Out of town? Pause a product's delivery indefinitely and resume with a click.",
                 placement: "bottom",
                 onPrev: function () {
                     $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first().click();
                 }
                },
                {element: $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first().find(".push"),
                 title: "3",
                 content: "If you need an item sooner than expected, push it to your next Dwellers Day.",
                 placement: "bottom"
                },
                {element: $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first().find(".rush"),
                 title: "4",
                 content: "If you really can't wait, rush it for next day delivery for $3.",
                 placement: "bottom"
                },
                {element: $("#monthly-chute-view .perspective-container").first(),
                 title: "5",
                 content: "Want to change frequencies? Just drag cards to different columns.",
                 placement: "bottom"
                },
                {element: "#menu-products",
                 title: "6",
                 content: "Check out the rest of our products and add the rest of the items on your shopping list.",
                 placement: "bottom",
                 onNext: function(tour){
                    tour.end();   
                 }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way you have is with JqueryUI, and the methods draggable() and droppable()
[JqueryUI Droppable Method](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)
[JqueryUI Draggable Method](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)